# Segmentation fault error based on the data format of a vector

Tags: c++, vector

I am new to stack overflow and coding. Currently, I am developing an algorithm. There I used  `vector<vector<double>>` type object will say it is as **a**. I correctly push backed values into that vector. I tested the values via a for loop as follows

```
 vector<vector<double>> a = getValuesofA(); // 
    // The test loop
      for (unsigned int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++) {
         for (unsigned int y = 0; y < a.at(i).size(); y++) {
            double x = a.at(i).at(y);
            std::cout << x << " ";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

 // Out put
0.278805 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0
0 0.00838826 0 0 0
0 0.276585 0 0 0
```

but when i pass to **a** libarary i get Segmentation fault Error.

Then i created b as follows from the output of a

```
vector<vector<double>> b = {{0.278805, 0, 0, 0, 0},
                                         {0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
                                         {0, 0.00838826, 0, 0, 0},
                                         {0, 0.276585, 0, 0, 0}};
```

when i pass b to that same library i dont get the error. result is as expected.
i have no idea what is the difference inbetween a and b. any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Have you used `valgrind` or a debugger?

Comment: @Stephen Newell nop

Comment: `valgrind` will complain loudly the first time you have a memory error, so give that a shot.

Comment: Please post the code of `getValuesofA`.

Comment: It is impossible to answer on you question without [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   for (auto &m : a) {
        for (auto &n : m) {
```

So m gets a pointer to a vector and n gets a pointer to a double.  However, in "b" the doubles are pointers, they are values.  In short, I suspect your libraries will work if you can get this to work:

```
for (auto &m : a) {
        for (auto n : m) {
```

Note the missing "&".

Comment: Check `a` and `b` again; they're both `vector<vector<double>>`

Comment: @Frank i changed  to  for (auto n : m) but i get the same output of a.

Comment: Yeah, but I'm guessing C++ auto converts "b" in some way . . . n is not an address as shown in "b", yet he picks it up as one.  Its been awhile since I've lived inside C++, so my answer might not be technically correct, but I'll bet the answer is in that general direction.

Comment: @Frank i check with the the given type. thank you Frank

Comment: @Frank please find my updated question. as you suggest i checked with the manual loop. But same problem.

Comment: Can you post getValuesOfA() as requested above.  Also, what library routine are you calling?  What is the signature of that routine?